# Google Play services are updating Error while building System Application for Marshamallow

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-maps-api-2

I have been facing a problem in Google Maps fragment. I'm trying to build an App for a client who is Android Device manufacturer. The has to be a System application which is installed in /system/priv-app folder.

Also my client needs to have all the Permissions by default like : READ_CALL_LOGS,
READ_SMS (Dangerous Permissions). For this I mentioned the following tag in the manifest.

```
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
```

After building the application and signing it with the platform certificates of the Android AOSP Code , I successfully get all the permissions .
But when I Open the Google Maps Fragment in my application.
It doesn't loads Google Maps but shows the text :

> Google Play services are updating

My Google play service Version is up to Date till 10.2.98.

Also when i open Map Fragment in my application , i get the following logs:

**E/ChimeraCfgMgr: Failed to read module config: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/current_config.pb: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**

I further checked that current_config.pb is already there in the device at its
above mentioned place.